# Custom vote up/down arrows

Tags: discussion, design

I've noticed that a lot of other sites have custom up and down arrows (like the [linux & unix](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/125509/linux-collect-only-the-modified-logs-every-day) site, for example.)  Is it possible for us to do that hear?  I think having the up and down arrows being flying wings like the B2 would be pretty cool. 
[image: See how it looks like a down arrow for a down vote!]

Or maybe N9-M, for the uber geeky.
[image: a little more simple, I like that.]

Though, for the less "modern" feel we could simply go with the [standard commercial outline](http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/0/05/Air_France_Boeing_777-228ER_Kustov_planform_view.jpg), which is still very reminiscent of an arrow.
[image: Maybe a 757 would be better than a 777?]

I think going with a GA plane would be a mistake, but that's just me, not "arrowy" enough without swept back wings.  Maybe someone can think of a way to make it work though?
[image: Though maybe a 152 is a bad example...]

Any thoughts?  Can we do this?  Would it not be awesome!  I say we go for it!

Comment: I think that we have to get out of beta before we get a custom site design, which would include the arrows. I like the top one, although maybe more of the outline or a "blueprint" version of it would look better since it will be so small.

Comment: @Lnafziger I'd agree, this is just or illustrative purposes.  We'd need to find someone with a little bit of graphical talent to whip up a simplified outline of the B2.

Comment: Something like that pilot wings badge would be nice too rather than a plane.

Comment: @PatoSáinz Maybe the pilots wings could be a custom "Favorites" badge?  I worry that if you turned it upside down it would look really weird...

Comment: @JayCarr definitely an interesting idea. For a visual impression of how it might look check out [gaming.se] -- their arrows are stylized ships reminiscent of something you'd see in Space Invaders

Comment: Great idea - a stylized B2 or airliner planform view would work well.

Comment: The stealth bomber would be good for the downvote array since neither stealth aircraft or bad posts want to be seen.

Comment: As much as I like the flying wing shapes I think if we go with stylized up/down vote arrows we should go with either a cessna-style planform or an airliner/jet planform, only because [Arqade](http://gaming.stackexchange.com) already uses something that's very close to the B2 outline

Comment: @voretaq7 You may have a point, but, frankly, I'm not sure it's that big of a deal if our arrows look kinda of like their arrows....  They are all arrows after all, they're going to look alike.

Comment: Whatever is chosen, the signs must be quite clear. A plane (such as the one chosen for badges) pointing up or down that looks like an arrow should be OK.

Answer (score 3):

How about departure and arrival signs?

[image]

[Source](http://thumb7.shutterstock.com/display_pic_with_logo/2535709/335913185/stock-vector-airport-arrivals-and-departures-sign-335913185.jpg)

Answer (score 2):

How about attitude indicators indicating nose up or nose down?  This would be very not arrow-y, but I think it would be cool.  A profile view showing a climbing or descending aircraft would be neat.  I'm also interested in seeing *some* GA design element on the site.

Comment: Or a VSI showing climb and descent...

Comment: As a non-pilot, I'd find both of those options confusing.  From past experience with Stack Exchange sites I'd understand they're the upvote and downvote buttons, but I'd only realize they represent a climbing or descending aircraft if someone pointed it out to me.