# Miniature icon looks kind of a little like a "smudge"

Tags: bug, status-completed, design

The new design is great, thank you!

There is one thing we talked about over [in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/12036/the-hangar), the small icon which is featured in the favicon, the HNQ, and the network selector menu, is barely recognizable, and kind of looks like a red blob. It seems like it's simply a scaled down version of the large logo, and the antialiasing/filtering is trying to make the most of the narrow lines.

I'm guessing it could use some accentuated/wider lines within the logo, or something else that would make it recognizable.

Thanks again.

Comment: Exactly the feeling and conclusion I have. The icon was not designed but obtained by resizing.

Comment: The first thing I thought when I saw it in the HNQ was that it looks like a moustache.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like this was taken care of in [the July 5 update](https://aviation.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3008/new-site-design) -- the site icon was "de-winged" and the lines made more prominent:

[image: New logo in site chooser]