# Voting arrows look selected when they're not

Tags: bug, status-completed, design, voting

I just went to a question I had already voted on, and wasn't sure which way I had voted:

[image]

Intuitively, it seems that the brighter arrow (down) would be the direction I voted - but I actually upvoted the post.

Compare to a post I haven't voted on:

[image]

The arrows feel too bright overall; distracting from the content of the post.

Could they be toned down a little?

Comment: Totally agree, and I just made similar comments about it in the Hanger chatroom.

Comment: Literally signed up to upvote this

Comment: @abelenky heh. I was so sure it was you who posted, didn't even check who did... sorry Undo.. ;)

Comment: Most every other SE site has colorless=unselected, and the buttons gain color when clicked.  When you visit a page here for the first time, it looks like you've already voted the question both up and down.  :)

Comment: @BenMiller That was my feeling too. Oh, and a little bit more contrast for the vote buttons here on Meta, too, maybe? :-)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed) Please see the update of [the original post](https://aviation.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3008/new-site-design/3024).

Answer (score 13):

I'd be in favor of reversing the colors (make "unselected" arrows dark & "selected" ones light) - I think that would make the difference more intuitive and the unvoted arrows less obtrusive - probably with the least work :)

Answer (score 9):

I agree with this complaint!  At first glance, would you say that I upvoted or downvoted the question below?

[image: Upvote/downvote screenshot on Aviation]

When I visited the site the first time after the redesign, I thought: "Why did I downvote such a good question?"  On Stack Exchange sites, the more brightly coloured arrow is the one what was selected.  **(When you press the flight attendant call button, it lights up, right?)**

Compare that with Stack Overflow, where the display is unambiguous:

[image: Upvote/downvote screenshot on Stack Overflow]

I believe that the colours you have chosen are reversed.  In any case, it is a confusing colour pair.  For clarity, the arrow not selected should ideally be light gray.  Please fix it.