# Possible Improvements in the site theme design

Tags: discussion, design

Possible small improvements:

1. In the toolbar pulldown lists, the highlighted rows are difficult to see, at least on my display (thinkpad), when not looking under the right view angle. The blue background is too light:

   [image]
2. In the continuation of [Farhan's suggestion](https://aviation.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3008/new-site-design?cb=1#3010) about buttons color, this is the same for the selection checkmark, the vivid blue of an unselected checkmark suggests a selected post until we see another unselected post with the same color, if it exists.
3. BTW, I don't like the vivid blue. 

   [image]

   It looks aggressive, a more matte shade would be better for me. Eyes are attracted by the colon of blue arrows in a page with short posts:

   [image]

   Maybe something like that would be possible, given the other constraints:

   [image]

   Or maybe the good magenta omnipresent in aviation displays:

   [image]

Comment: The vivid blue complaint has now been filed as [a separate question](/questions/3022/blue-color-is-too-vivid).

Comment: Totally agreed I got confused **Several** times because of the unselected state of the arrows

Comment: The favicon (logo without the wings, what shows up in the titlebar) looks like a picnic table.