# Blue color is too vivid

Tags: discussion, status-completed, design

We already have a few posts describing the blue voting arrows. This post is about the blue text at the front page:

[image]

1. The blue color is ***way*** too attractive to the eye. For an
   exercise, try scrolling through the list looking for a particular
   question. I felt it burnt my eyes.
2. The tags use the same color as the question text, which is wrong. The tags should use a duller, less attractive color, as they do not share the same visual priority with the question text.

I find the color scheme of the meta site to be much better - the grey color renders the text comprehendible, which is most important for any website.

Answer (score 12):

100% agree, the blue is definitely too bright

Answer (score 4):

[status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed) Please see the update of [the original post](https://aviation.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3008/new-site-design/3024).

Comment: I see it. Better now. Though I meant the color of all blue text in general, not just the question text...

Comment: I agree with Kevin: I still think the tags below questions, and the username of the last-modified are too bright blue.

Comment: I agree with @abelenky: the tags now stand out more than the questions for me so it's difficult to skim visually down the page because the tags keep distracting me and pulling my eyes away.

Comment: I think the blues in the tags need to be desaturated to the point of almost being gray (or perhaps, they could just be gray.)  Point being, I agree with the above.  The brightness of the tags, especially, is creating visual confusion between the titles and the tags and is creating a "wall of text'" effect that makes it hard to skim down the page.  Something that is crucial to the UX of any good SE site...

Comment: I'll desaturate all the blues then and see if there's a better alternative for the tags :)

Comment: Thanks Stéphane, the question list looks so much better!