# Aviation logo is unreadable when displayed too small

Tags: bug, status-completed, design

On some views, especially the hot-network section, out logo appear in very small.

It is absolutely impossible to distinguish what it is, appart from a bunch of red pixels next to each other. This contrast quite well from the other logo which remain quite distinct.

Maybe not filling the inside would help in making it more readable ?

[image: le tas de pixels en question]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed) Please see the update of [the original post](https://aviation.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3008/new-site-design/3024).